# Javascript not working properly on button

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have created a web page using bootstrap. There are 2 text boxes and a button to submit. I have written JavaScript function to give an alert if any text field is empty. I am amazed to see that it is not working. My JavaScript function is:

```
function validateForm()
{
var a=document.forms["Form"]["field1"].value;
var b=document.forms["Form"]["field2"].value;
if(a=="" && b=="")
{
alert("Both fields are required");
  return false;
}else if (a==null || a=="")
  {
  alert("Field 1 is required");
  return false;
  }else if (b==null || b=="")
  {
  alert("Field 2 is required");
  return false;
  }else if(a!="" && b!="")
  {
  alert("Submitted Successfully");
  return true;
  }
}
```

My form code is:

```
<form role="form" method="post" name="Form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">   
    <div class="row 150%">
        <div class="6u 12u$(medium)">
            <input class="form-control" name="field1" id="ex1" type="text" autofocus placeholder="First Text Field">
        </div>
        <div class="6u 12u$(medium)">
            <input class="form-control" name="field2" id="ex2" type="text" autofocus placeholder="Second Text Field">
        </div>
    </div><br /><br />
    <button id="submit" class="button" style="vertical-align:middle">
        <span>Submit </span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: I just tested this and it seems to work perfectly fine. There must be some other problem in your code.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjdxNX works ok.

Comment: try to replace the button tag with this <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit"/>

Comment: Code works this side as well. If this script is external check your link statement.

Answer (score 0):

How have you included the validateForm javascript?

for instance the following works for me:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>

function validateForm()
{
var a=document.forms["Form"]["field1"].value;
var b=document.forms["Form"]["field2"].value;
if(a=="" && b=="")
{
alert("Both fields are required");
  return false;
}else if (a==null || a=="")
  {
  alert("Field 1 is required");
  return false;
  }else if (b==null || b=="")
  {
  alert("Field 2 is required");
  return false;
  }else if(a!="" && b!="")
  {
  alert("Submitted Successfully");
  return true;
  }
}
</script>
<form role="form" method="post" name="Form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">   
    <div class="row 150%">
    <div class="6u 12u$(medium)">
        <input class="form-control" name="field1" id="ex1" type="text" autofocus placeholder="First Text Field">
    </div>
    <div class="6u 12u$(medium)">
        <input class="form-control" name="field2" id="ex2" type="text" autofocus placeholder="Second Text Field">
    </div>
    </div><br /><br />
    <button id="submit" class="button" style="vertical-align:middle">
    <span>Submit </span>
    </button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is not an answer, just a question with the OP's code included. When you have sufficient rep, you can post a comment

Comment: I have attached an answer. It consist of whole code.